# verify signed response for FB.getLoginStatus

Tags: facebook

Anyone have code to verify the response returned from **FB.getLoginStatus**?
This is an example response.

```
{ "session":{
  "uid":"000000000000000",
  "session_key":"0.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa0.0000.0000000000.0-000000000000000",
  "secret":"aa0a0_aaaaa0_aa0aaaaaa__",
  "expires":0000000000,
  "base_domain":"foo.com",
  "access_token":"000000000000000|0.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa0.0000.0000000000.0-000000000000000|0aaa0aaaaaa00aaaaaa0aaaa-0a",
  "sig":"00aa0a0000000000a00a00aaa00a00a0"
  },
  "status":"connected",
  "perms":"{"extended":["email","contact_email"],"user":["user_birthday"],"friends":[]}"
}
```

How do you verify the signature, secret, etc?
I have the FB App Secret, but unsure what needs to be hased (HMACSHA256) to match the **sig** value?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you need to verify it at all?

Answer (score 0):

fix, use new oauth param in FB.init() and then verify signed request using example from registration, etc

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/